# Implement a presistent B-Tree

Tags: java, c++, b-tree

I'm interested to implement a presistent B-Tree using either c++ or java, as I need to store some path expressions e.g. //scientist/person/... /[Albert Einstein].

I tried google, but I was not satisfied. Some hints on this would be very helpful, or any ideas as where to start with. The BTree must be stored on the the disk however.

Comment: http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/V1.0/doc/api/jdbm/btree/BTree.html exists.  Can you use this?

Comment: http://idlebox.net/2010/stx-cbtreedb/ (c++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using pointers, instead use index from a base address.
This way you can simply mmap the btree into memory and use the base address along with the index as a lookup.

If using windows look at mapview of file instead.

Comment: exactly my thought. However, it is worth mentioning that these things exist and are called databases. You can have implementations of that in one file of statically linkable c-code (sqlite e.g.)

Comment: This may not work because there may be many allocations from dynamic memory between allocations of nodes in the B-Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [qdbm](http://fallabs.com/qdbm/)?